# Running Sum in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (fgt_curate.orders.ordernumber)) AS cnt,
             fgt_curate.d_datetable.Weeknum
      FROM fgt_curate.orders
        LEFT JOIN fgt_curate.d_datetable ON fgt_curate.d_datetable.Date_Key = fgt_curate.orders.Orderdatekey
      WHERE YEAR> 2020
      AND   cancelled = FALSE
      AND   fgt_curate.d_datetable.Weeknum <= 11
      GROUP BY fgt_curate.d_datetable.Weeknum
```

Which outputs a table similar to below:

| cnt | weeknum |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 |
| 18 | 2 |
| 23 | 3 |
| 12 | 4 |

All I'm trying to do is to add a new column that calculates the cumulative sum.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT fgt_curate.orders.ordernumber) AS cnt,`, to make code clearer

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the fgt_curate.d_datetable conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @Roham . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Amazon Redshift. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be:

```
SELECT d.Weeknum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.ordernumber) AS cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT o.ordernumber)) OVER (ORDER BY d.Weeknum) as running_cnt
FROM fgt_curate.orders o LEFT JOIN 
     fgt_curate.d_datetable d
     ON d.Date_Key = o.Orderdatekey
WHERE d.YEAR > 2020 AND
      o.cancelled = FALSE AND
      d.Weeknum <= 11
GROUP BY d.Weeknum;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.
- Qualify *all* column references so the source is clear.  I had to guess for most columns in your query.
- The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join.  You should change it (but I did not do so above).
- `DISTINCT` is NOT a function in `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  The parentheses around `o.ordernumber` are superfluous.
- I imagine that `ordernumber` is unique in a table called `orders`.  If so, just use `COUNT(*)`.

EDIT:

I would speculate that you want to get all weeks during the specified period.  If so, the structure would be:

```
SELECT d.Weeknum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.ordernumber) AS cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT o.ordernumber)) OVER (ORDER BY d.Weeknum) as running_cnt
FROM fgt_curate.d_datetable d LEFT JOIN
     fgt_curate.orders o 
     ON o.Orderdatekey = d.Date_Key AND
        o.cancelled = FALSE 
WHERE d.YEAR > 2020 AND
      d.Weeknum <= 11
GROUP BY d.Weeknum;
```

The table where you want to keep all rows (dates) goes first.  Any filtering on that table is in the `WHERE` clause.  Any filtering on subsequent tables is in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I receive the following error when running this query:
 Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause